# XPath to <p> which which doesn't has directly assigned class

Tags: html, xpath

I got a problem, i need to exclude some "price" class tags which have above themself "promoted-list" class. Here is an example

```
<table class="promoted-list">
<td>
<p class="price">I dont want this one</p>
</td>
</table>

<table>
<td>
<p class="price">I want this one</p>
</td>
</table>
```

I can't access via XPath this 1000 using:

```
//p[contains(@class, 'price') and not(contains(@class, 'promoted-list'))]
```

It just doesn't want to exclude this one, does anyone has a solution?
In this case output should be "I want this one"

Comment: Your provided code does not contain class `example1`. Please update your question.

Comment: This question is unclear. Please make your XML document consistent with the description, and clarify what you expect as the output.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Fixed, i hope it's clear enought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardind the website link you posted, use these XPaths to get what you need (only prices with white rectangles background).

Notes :

Some articles have no price, so XPaths should always return the same number for article and price (number of article = number of price).
"Zamienię" is excluded.

```
//td[normalize-space(@class)="offer" and contains(.,"zł")]//h3//strong/text()
//td[normalize-space(@class)="offer" and contains(.,"zł")]//p/strong/text()
```

If you want to keep "Zamienię" :

```
//td[normalize-space(@class)="offer"][*//p[@class="price"]]//h3//strong/text()
//td[normalize-space(@class)="offer"]//p[@class="price"]/strong/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a well-formed sample XML document, such as

```
<root>
<table class="promoted-list">
<td>
<p class="price">I dont want this one</p>
</td>
</table>

<table>
<td>
<p class="price">I want this one</p>
</td>
</table>
</root>
```

an XPath expression to accomplish that would be:

```
//table[not(contains(@class, 'promoted-list'))]//p[contains(@class, 'price')]
```

In plain English, it means

```
//table[not(contains(@class, 'promoted-list'))]//p[contains(@class, 'price')]

select all `table` elements,
       but only if they do not have a `class` attribute whose value includes "promoted-list
                                               of the remaining `table` elements, select all `p` descendant elements
                                                  but only if they have a `class` attribute whose value contains "price"
```

**Output**

```
<p class="price">I want this one</p>
```

Comment: @GrzegorzBarański If that does not work, then the XML document you are showing is not representative of your real problem, i.e. you are leaving out something important.

Comment: Can i send you link to this website?

Comment: @GrzegorzBarański No, you should include this link, or other necessary information, in your question. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.olx.pl/pomorskie/q-macbook/
Scroll a little bit below and you have 5 rectangles with cream color background, and on the right side of it you have price .... zl. Those i want to exclude. Only prices i want to include are those below, rectangles with white background

Comment: @GrzegorzBarański:  It's your responsibility to create a [mcve] such that the question alone has everything needed to answer.  There should be no need to visit an offsite link as those tend to go stale and provide no benefit to future readers.  Please make your question into a proper [mcve] to avoid wasting answers' time solving the wrong problem for you.